# Spark Streaming job fails after new partitions are assigned(old are revoked)for kafka topic : No current assignment for partition topic1

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, offset, kafka-consumer-api

Using spark streaming with kafka and creating a direct stream using below code-

```
val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> conf.getString("kafka.brokers"),
  "zookeeper.connect" -> conf.getString("kafka.zookeeper"),
  "group.id" -> conf.getString("kafka.consumergroups"),
  "auto.offset.reset" -> args { 1 },
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (conf.getString("kafka.autoCommit").toBoolean: java.lang.Boolean),
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "security.protocol" -> "SASL_PLAINTEXT",
  "session.timeout.ms" -> args { 2 },
  "max.poll.records" -> args { 3 },
  "request.timeout.ms" -> args { 4 },
  "fetch.max.wait.ms" -> args { 5 })

val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  ssc,
  LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent,
  ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](topicsSet, kafkaParams))
```

After some processing we commit the offset using commitAsync API.

```
try
{
messages.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
  messages.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges)
}
}
catch
{   
 case e:Throwable => e.printStackTrace()
}
```

Below error causes the job to crash-

```
            18/03/20 10:43:30 INFO ConsumerCoordinator: Revoking previously assigned partitions [TOPIC_NAME-3, TOPIC_NAME-5, TOPIC_NAME-4] for group 21_feb_reload_2
            18/03/20 10:43:30 INFO AbstractCoordinator: (Re-)joining group 21_feb_reload_2
            18/03/20 10:43:30 INFO AbstractCoordinator: (Re-)joining group 21_feb_reload_2
            18/03/20 10:44:00 INFO AbstractCoordinator: Successfully joined group 21_feb_reload_2 with generation 20714
            18/03/20 10:44:00 INFO ConsumerCoordinator: Setting newly assigned partitions [TOPIC_NAME-1, TOPIC_NAME-0, TOPIC_NAME-2] for group 21_feb_reload_2
            18/03/20 10:44:00 ERROR JobScheduler: Error generating jobs for time 1521557010000 ms
            java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current assignment for partition TOPIC_NAME-4
                at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState.assignedState(SubscriptionState.java:251)
                at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState.needOffsetReset(SubscriptionState.java:315)
                at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.seekToEnd(KafkaConsumer.java:1170)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.latestOffsets(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:197)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.compute(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:214)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
                at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
                at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.compute(MappedDStream.scala:36)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
                at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
                at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.generateJob(ForEachDStream.scala:48)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:117)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:116)
                at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
                at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
                at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
                at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
                at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
                at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.generateJobs(DStreamGraph.scala:116)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:249)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:247)
                at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.generateJobs(JobGenerator.scala:247)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:183)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:89)
                at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:88)
                at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
            18/03/20 10:44:00 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current assignment for partition
```

My findings -

1- Similar issue from the post -[Kafka Spark Stream throws Exception:No current assignment for partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156571/kafka-spark-stream-throws-exceptionno-current-assignment-for-partition) 
This does not give much explanation to why use Assign rather than Subscribe.

2- Tying to make sure there is no re-balancing, I increased the session.timeout.ms to almost my batch duration as my processing gets completed in less than 2 min(batch duration).

session.timeout.ms-
The amount of time a consumer can be out of contact with the brokers while still considered alive 
(https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/ch04.html)

3- Came across Re-balance Listeners with methods -
a onPartitionsRevoked
b onPartitionsAssigned

But was unable to understand how can I use the first one which commits offset just before rebalancing.

Any Inputs will be much appreciated.

Comment: What was the solution? We have a similar issue in spark 2.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. when two of my spark jobs are using the same kafka client.id .So i have assigned the new kafka client for another job